# Strange behavior with a "confirm" modal jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I am trying to make a modal act like a confirm button. You click the button, a popup opens up and askes yes or no, if yes, stores some info in database, removes that item from the DOM then adds an item somewhere else. But, right now, if they click the confirm "yes", it runs the ajax call multiple times. I feel like it is running it for other places where data-express="yes" but I don't know why it could...shouldn't $(this) only be the button that is clicked? I don't see what in here would make it run more than one time.

The button -

```
<ul class="list-inline center-block">
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block express_button" data-confirm="yes" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button></li>
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block express_button" data-confirm="no" data-dismiss="modal">No</button></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.snf_interest').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).find('input[name=resid]').val();
  var ppcode = $('.placement_item_' + id + ' .pdcode' + id).text();
  var ppdate = $('.placement_item_' + id + ' .pp_date').text();
  var dcpname = $(this).find('input[name=dcpname]').val();
  var dcpemail = $(this).find('input[name=dcpemail]').val();
  var prefcom = $(this).find('input[name=prefcom]').val();
  var ppid = $(this).find('input[name=ppid]').val();
  var patientneeds = $('.placement_item_' + id + '       .patientneeds').text();
  var dcphone = $('.placement_item_' + id + ' .dcphone').text();
  var dcnote = $(this).find('input[name=notes]').val();
  $('#express_interest_modal').modal();
  //if(confirm('Are you sure you want to express interest in this patient')){
  $('.express_button').on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this));
  if($(this).data('confirm') == 'yes'){
  $.ajax({
     // url: "/snf/express_interest",
      type: "POST",
      data: { 'ppid' : ppid,
            'status' : status,
            'dcpname' : dcpname,
            'dcpemail' : dcpemail,
            'prefcom' : prefcom 
             },
      success:function(){
     // $('#interest_modal').modal('show');
      $('#panel-placement .panel-body').append('<ul class="list-group list-group-no-pad"><li class="list-group-item clearfix well well-sm"><label>'+ppcode+'| Posted: '+ppdate+'</label><form class="pull-right" action="http://dev.goodcareconnection.com/snf/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ppid" value="'+ppid+'"><div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."><input class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" name="ppbutn" value="Hide This Patient"></div></form></li><li class="list-group-item clearfix"><div class="col-md-12"><label>Needs: <h5 class="patientneeds">'+patientneeds+'</h5></label></div></li><li class="list-group-item clearfix"><div class="col-md-4"><label>Posted by: <h5>'+dcpname+'</h5></label></div><div class="col-md-4"><label>Email: <h5>'+dcpemail+'</h5></label></div><div class="col-md-4"><label>Phone: <h5>(303) 570-9863 M: (303) 570-9863</h5></label></div></li><li class="list-group-item clearfix"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><h5><label>Notes</label></h5><textarea id="ppnote35" class="form-control update_note" name="notes" readonly="">'+dcnote+'</textarea></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><form class="snf_interest"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" name="submit">Remove Interest</button></form></div></li></ul>');
        $('.placement_item_'+ppid).remove();    
        var number = $('.express_badge').html();
        number = parseInt(number);
        number = number + 1;
        $('.express_badge').html(number);
        var number = $('.bulletin_count').html();
        number = parseInt(number);
        number = number - 1; 
        $('.bulletin_count').html(number);
      } 
  })
 }
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from adding one event handler inside another event handler.

The first time submit is triggered...the `express_button` elements do not have a click handler that would do the ajax previously attached. It gets added in this first submit event

Clicking "Yes" should only do make one ajax request.

The next time submit is triggered it will add the same event handler again.
Now clicking "Yes" will run 2 instances of the event handler and make 2 requests.

Every submit will increment the number of requests made

A simple solution would be remove the click handler as soon as it gets used.
Beware though that if modal gets closed using methods other than the buttons the event handler will still be there and problem will persist

```
  $('.express_button').on('click', function(){
     $(this).off('click')
     // other code    
  });
```

A better solution would be separate the submit and click handlers by storing the data that needs to be sent so it would be accessible when "Yes" is clicked